# how to sort content of div using select tag and jquery function change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to sort the content of div on the basis of variable named risk, whose value lies between 1 to 10.
screen shot of page:

[link to screenshot of my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvBvz.png)

I have used select tag of html and change function of jquery, but i am not getting how to use them, as i am beginner in javascript.
I have only three categories in select tag i.e high risk, low risk, medium risk and i wants to sort according to these categories.

```
1<=low risk<4
4<=medium risk<7
7<=high risk<=10
```

**jquery function i am using is:-**

```
    $("select").change(function(){
     alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
```

In short i wants to sort the data then re-display on the page.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I presume you mean sort the data then re-display on the page? This question is a bit unclear

Comment: yes, you got it right

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```js
$("#select").change(function() {
  var target = $(this).val();
  $(".test").removeClass("active");
  $(target).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: none;
}

.test.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1" class="test active">div 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="test">div 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="test">div 3</div>

<select name="" id="select">
  <option value="#test1">show div 1</option>
  <option value="#test2">show div 2</option>
  <option value="#test3">show div 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is there any other efficient method to do it,  if we will use this method then there will be lot of html syntax.

Comment: use data attr instead of value